# Best way to import sequelize models in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize orm in node.js. I have made models folders for all model like userModel.js, in userModel.js I have some class-based functions like login and getToken.

```
// some code of userModel.js 

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const UserSchema = sequelize.define('User', {
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        });

    // generate token
    UserSchema.genToken = (id) => {
        return jwt.sign({ id }, 'test');
    }

    // user login 
    UserSchema.login = function (body) {
        const User = this;
        return User.findOne({
                where: { email: body.email}
            })
            .then((result) => {
                return result;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return Promise.reject(err);
            })
    }
    return UserSchema;
}
```

when i import userModel.js in db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = {};
var db = {};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.User = sequelize.import('./../models/userModel');

module.exports = db;
```

so my question is when I using db variable for userModel like

> db.User

I am using VS code editor for coding. So now VS code is showing me all suggestion of sequelize models but it is not showing my functions for login and genToken

```
//suggest
db.User.find()
db.User.findOne()

//but not include these
db.User.login()
db.User.genToken()
```

Even when I use `db.User.login()` or `db.User.genToken()` it's working as I want but right now I will have to open userModel.js again and again for seeing the name of all functions. How can I import models in a better way?

Comment: Are these methods `login` and `genToken` defined on the Model UserModel?

Comment: yes, I have added these functions login and geToken in userModel, please see my first code section above and find (UserSchema.login)